# android Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
it Ocuure Illigal statement exception and JsonSyntaxException

This is content from my RegisterFragment:

```
User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);
registerProcess(user);

 private void registerProcess(User user) {

    mSubscriptions.add(NetworkUtil.getRetrofit().register(user)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse, this::handleError));
}
private void handleResponse(MyResponse response) {

    mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    showSnackBarMessage(response.getMessage());
}
```

private void handleError(Throwable error) {

```
    mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (error instanceof HttpException) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        try {

            String errorBody = ((HttpException) error).response().errorBody().string();
            MyResponse response = gson.fromJson(errorBody, MyResponse.class);
           Log.i(TAG, "handleError: "+ response.getMessage());
            showSnackBarMessage(response.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

        showSnackBarMessage("Network Error !");
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your json response here.

Comment: Share you JSON and Parsing code

Comment: private void handleError(Throwable error) {
        mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (error instanceof HttpException) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                String errorBody = ((HttpException) error).response().errorBody().string();
                MyResponse response = gson.fromJson(errorBody, MyResponse.class);
               
          
    }

Comment: We don't (only) need the code how you received your Jason but the content of the received Jason itself. And please don't add information as comment but rather edit your question and add additional information there.